# How to Make Column Names an actual column in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

A small sample of the data I'm working with is below:

```
structure(list(`Team Code` = c(107, 277, 129, 1320, 27, 694, 
231, 306, 314, 465), `Opponent Code` = c(277, 107, 1320, 129, 
694, 27, 306, 231, 465, 314), Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), Date = structure(c(17040, 
17040, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045
), class = "Date"), HomeTeam = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1
), Points = c(51, 31, 49, 3, 13, 20, 13, 34, 13, 63), OppPoints = c(31, 
51, 3, 49, 20, 13, 34, 13, 63, 13), Total = c(82, 82, 52, 52, 
33, 33, 47, 47, 76, 76), MOV = c(-20, 20, -46, 46, 7, -7, 21, 
-21, 50, -50), Spread = c(-22, 22, -32, 32, 22.5, -22.5, 4, -4, 
40, -40)), row.names = c(1489L, 1490L, 297L, 298L, 1453L, 1454L, 
1915L, 1916L, 2121L, 2122L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am needing to create a new data frame that brings in Unique Year, Date, and then the column names. I've been able to do this for the Points and OppPoints columns with the below code, but when I extend it beyond those two columns I get length errors. The desired output is exactly like below, just would like more rows added for Total, MOV, and Spread.

Code I've tried and gotten length Errors:

```
Data$Stat_Name <- colnames(Data[,6:10])
```

Code that produces part of the desired result:

```
Data$Stat_Name <- colnames(Data[,6:10])
```

Partial Desired Result:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016), Date = structure(c(17040, 17040, 17045, 17045, 17046, 
17046, 17047, 17047), class = "Date"), Stat_Name = c("Points", 
"OppPoints", "Points", "OppPoints", "Points", "OppPoints", "Points", 
"OppPoints")), row.names = c(1489L, 1490L, 297L, 298L, 355L, 
356L, 85L, 86L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You may need to `paste(colnames(Data)[6:10], collapse = "_")` as the lengths are not equal to the number of rows

Comment: Is there any logic that you want to implement (as it is not clear from the post though)

Comment: Hey @akrun, there isn't any logic, other than I just need to have a data frame of all the unique combinations of the year, date, and column name column. I will be able to test your above code in just a little bit. Your above code is a really good idea. Then I can use separate rows and get the desired result! Thank you! If you will submit as an answer I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a single column with `paste` on the column names from 6 to 10 as the number of rows will not be equal to column names passed as a vector (or else have to create a `list` column

```
Data$Stat_Name <- paste(colnames(Data)[6:10], collapse = "_")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, Stat_Name = paste0(names(df[c(6:7, 9:10)]), collapse = '_'))
```

```
   Team Code Opponent Code Year       Date HomeTeam Points OppPoints Total MOV Spread                   Stat_Name
1        107           277 2016 2016-08-27        0     51        31    82 -20  -22.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
2        277           107 2016 2016-08-27        0     31        51    82  20   22.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
3        129          1320 2016 2016-09-01        1     49         3    52 -46  -32.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
4       1320           129 2016 2016-09-01        0      3        49    52  46   32.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
5         27           694 2016 2016-09-01        0     13        20    33   7   22.5 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
6        694            27 2016 2016-09-01        1     20        13    33  -7  -22.5 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
7        231           306 2016 2016-09-01        1     13        34    47  21    4.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
8        306           231 2016 2016-09-01        0     34        13    47 -21   -4.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
9        314           465 2016 2016-09-01        0     13        63    76  50   40.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
10       465           314 2016 2016-09-01        1     63        13    76 -50  -40.0 Points_OppPoints_MOV_Spread
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you need it

```
tibble(
  `Team Code` = c(107, 277, 129, 1320, 27, 694, 231, 306, 314, 465), 
  `Opponent Code` = c(277, 107, 1320, 129, 694, 27, 306, 231, 465, 314), 
  Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), 
  Date = structure(c(17040,17040, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045),class = "Date"), 
  HomeTeam = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
  Points = c(51, 31, 49, 3, 13, 20, 13, 34, 13, 63), 
  OppPoints = c(31,51, 3, 49, 20, 13, 34, 13, 63, 13), 
  Total = c(82, 82, 52, 52,33, 33, 47, 47, 76, 76), 
  MOV = c(-20, 20, -46, 46, 7, -7, 21, -21, 50, -50), 
  Spread = c(-22, 22, -32, 32, 22.5, -22.5, 4, -4,  40, -40)
)  %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=5:last_col(), names_to ="field", values_to ="val")
```